# Not getting json input in `req.get_json()` in azure function app in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, httprequest

I have created few apis before in azure function app. I had used req.get_json() to get the json input parameter but suddenly it stopped. The value of req.get_json() is giving me error `ValueError: HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data`. I tried following basic code sample. Its giving me the same error.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

curl command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:7071/api/dev-test' \
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
> --data-raw '{"name":"test-dev"}​'
```

output of curl:

```
This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.
```

Comment: What is the output when you use req.get_body()?

Comment: `b'{"name":"name"}\xe2\x80\x8b'` this is the output of `req.get_body()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced same issue before, this is mostly I think postman's issue. You can download [postcode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rohinivsenthil.postcode) extension for `vscode` from marketplace and test using it.

In the `curl` command you might also have issue as mentioned by `Frank` above. To remove that issue, you can instead create one `JSON` file and paste your json data in it and then try with curl like: `curl --location --request POST "http://localhost:7071/api/dev-test" --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @test.json` where `test.json` will contain your json data. It may or may not work.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the introduction of extra characters when copying. You can delete that line of parameters and manually enter the request parameters. There should be no more problems.

Enter this line manually:

```
--data-raw '{"name":"test-dev"}​'
```

Comment: @KomalNagada. These characters are invisible, and you'd better enter them character by character instead of just checking them.

Comment: I checked by entering manually its not working.

Comment: I checked through `Postman` and created a python client to check but both are also giving same error and same data in `req.get_body()`.